# jQuery offset not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am getting the value of an data-anchor for each "li" I click on and I use it to match the id value of list of divs

```
<div id="rateCardsContainer">
  <div id="one"><div>
  <div id="two"><div>
</div>
```

I am than using the following function so that when I click on li that has the same id as div than the div will scroll to the top:

```
AIG.RC.setModalEventsListener = function() {
    $(AIG.RC.LIST_NODE).on('click', 'li', function() {

        var currentID = $(this).attr('data-anchor');

        var currentOffset = $('#' + currentID).offset().top;

        console.log(currentOffset);


    $('#rateCardsContainer').animate({scrollTop:currentOffset}, 500);
    });
};
```

This "console.log(currentOffset);" returns very odd values as you can see.I click on the list on the left and the corresponding div on the right with same id should scroll to the top, however it has very irregular scrolls  [image]

Comment: Can you verify that all ID's are unique?

Comment: yes there are like so: one, two, three, four....